# Unlock OnePlus2 after reset and now in FRP

Tags: factory-reset, gmail, google-account

I have reset my Android Phone (OnePlus2) after it froze. Now it wants me to log in to my previously used Google account.

I know the PIN Code and the Code to Unlock the Screen and the fingerprint is also set to me. 
Is there a way to bypass this protection ?

IMHO this does not make any sense if there is no way. Any reasonable thief, who knows all this information can simply unlock the phone and disable OEM lock.

My only problem is that i forgot the Googlemail.

Comment: FRP, or Factory Reset Protection, is a Google security protocol built into  modern Android devices, and it is incredibly tough to bypass... Most "reasonable thieves" just ignore these devices because it is so difficult to bypass, it is hardly simple although some devices have specific exploits to bypass it, but those are becoming less and less common as security updates are rolled out on a more consistent basis. To have any chance at assistance, you will need to edit your post and include your specific device and Android version. TBH, the chances are slim you can bypass this.

Comment: If you read my answer, you will realise, that it is in fact incredibly easy. Although i also am surprised by this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched a few videos on youtube and found a comment, that i tried out of pure desperation:

**"Use this code to unlock in emergency call *#812# "**

... and it worked !!

After this code unlocks your phone, just go to settings and add a new google account.

Thanks a lot to Chris Rosario for the comment.

Comment: Just an FYI... this is NOT a universal way to bypass FRP, it just worked on your device (which you never told us what it is). Glad you got it working, but this method likely won't help others without knowing what device it is. 

BTW, I tried this on a few devices on our test bench... Nexus 5, Moto G 2015, Moto X Pure 2015, and Axon 7 Mini. Didn't work on any of them, I could get to dialing an emergency call on all devices but could not get to settings at all from there.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning ... i edited my question. I was sure i had already put it there. Thanks for the infos. You are probably right, the video i took this advice from was about a OnePlus3. Maybe its just a OnePlus thing. But the customer support there didnt know this trick.

Comment: TBH, I find it "unfortunate" that OnePlus made it this simple to bypass FRP... Kind defeats the whole purpose of it and lets you know that information and device is not safe at all.

Comment: I somehow agree. But the good news is, that google sure will find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

There are bypasses but it varies by phone. The best bet is to flash stock firmware. That's the only way I know to do it, because I've done it on my wife's Galaxy S5.

Comment: FYI... That doesn't work on most devices that released with Android 5.x or higher, the SGS5 released with KitKat. Android specifies that that FRP settings are stored in an encrypted, protected partition in all devices that shipped with Android 5 and above, flashing a factory image does not touch those partitions, similar to serial number, IMEI, and other device specific information.

Comment: I have seen online  where people  say you can't and you can I tried it and it did in fact remove the frp and was able to use the phone untill recently when the digitizer cracked when dropped

Comment: Then FRP on that device is flawed and useless, if it is so simple to bypass it is worthless.

Comment: Acejavelin please address the question that is the purpose of this site not discussing anwser to said qustion

Comment: And yes that wood make it useless I was extremely suprised it worked my self especially on a Samsung flagship

Comment: The point was your answer is not universal, it's actually an exception to the norm, and most likely does not apply to the OP unless they have the same model device. I didn't down vote it because of your low reputation, but it isn't a very good answer to the question as it was asked.

Comment: I appreciate you not down voting me and this was my  experience with frp at the time  the only real universial method is to know the info  but the op isn't as specific as it needs to be

Comment: @seanburk what is missing, to be as specific as you need it ? I contacted Google and they told me that i should send in the phone to OnePlus and they would put the OS back on and this should do the trick. She also added, that i could be able to do it myself, but only if i had some "computer knowledge" ...

Comment: What phone u have wood be a good start then and any and all things you have done to it root mods etc. I see oneplus  I am not familiar with those  at all never even seen one in person so  from here I'd say get the newwest EXACT FIRMWARE for your model of phone I've read that you can't downgrade stock firmware idk if it's true iv never tried but get the firmware and Google how to flash stock firmware for your phone and try it I wood stick to trusted site for info and all downloads I'm bias to this site and xda for this matter xda mite be a better place to look for what u need

Comment: @seanburk i called OnePlus and now have an appointment for a remote session for tomorrow evening. If it solves the problem i will report, and if it doesnt,  i will try it myself.

Comment: See my own answer for the solution.